# ManagedCuda: IllegalAddress; While Executing a Kernel

Tags: c#, cuda

I am using the ManagedCuda library in a C# project to utilise the GPU, currently I am following along with this [tutorial](https://algoslaves.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/nvidia-cuda-hello-world-in-managed-c-and-f-with-use-of-managedcuda/) regarding how to write code compatible between C# and C++ after failing to achieve it with OpenCV.

Everything seems to be working fine with my code, the kernel is found, built and the method call is executed however I am getting an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'ManagedCuda.CudaException' occurred in ManagedCuda.dll

Additional information: ErrorIllegalAddress: While executing a kernel, the device 
encountered a load or store instruction on an invalid memory address.

The context cannot be used, so it must be destroyed (and a new one should be created).
```

I understand that C# is complaining that a valid address is not found when it attempts to pass the device pointer to the kernel, the only difference I can tell between my code and the post in the cited tutorial, is that ManagedCuda seems to have recently had a facelift which allows users to use Lambdas, I've done some reading and haven't found anything to clarify whether or not this is what's causing my problem:

```
static Func<int, int, int> cudaAdd = (a, b) =>
{
    // init output parameters
    CudaDeviceVariable<int> result_dev = 0;
    int result_host = 0;
    // run CUDA method
    addWithCuda.Run(a, b, result_dev.DevicePointer);   <--- Code throws error here
    // copy return to host
    result_dev.CopyToHost(ref result_host);
    return result_host;
};
```

In the original tutorial code the OP uses `CudaDeviceVariable result_dev = 0;`. Could this be the problem? I don't see why it would be, but maybe my cast is wrong?

For clarity here is the kernel which is being called:

```
__global__ void kernel(int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c = (a + b)*(a + b);
}
```

Comment: Your sample code runs without errors on my PC and returns the right result. Can you check that you load the right kernel file from the right folder? And what grid/block sizes are you using? CudaDeviceVariable without any "<type>" is not defined and should not compile, so this is not the reason. Also lambdas do not affect managedCuda in any way: as long as the variables a and b that you pass to the kernel are well defined ints, managedCuda doesn’t care about the rest. If all this doesn’t help, try to debug the kernel with NSight to see what memory access causes the troubles.

Comment: I think it might be because I was trying to run it from a gui based app. The same code executes and returns a result on a console application.   Any ideas why

Comment: A GUI based app probably runs in different threads and a Cuda context is always bound to one single thread. Despite managedCuda should then actually throw an InvalidContext-exception, I would try to set the context current to the active thread by calling ctx.SetCurrent() before any Cuda operation. But this is error prone if not done properly; I always try to keep one thread exclusive to all Cuda operations to avoid multiple threads to operate on the same context at any time.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense.  Unfortunately it isn't so well documented how to write gui apps with Cuda.  If you want to post that as an answer I'd be happy to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it seems that the thrown exception is due to running on different threads. In a single threaded environment the sample code runs fine returning the right result. In order to use Cuda in a multithreaded application, proper synchronization of the threads and binding the cuda context to the currently active threads would be necessary.

Comment: Addition: I recently encountered the same error when loading a PTX compiled for 32 bit while running a 64 bit application. Only Cubin-kernel throw an ErrorInvalidImage-exception, whereas PTX-kernel get loaded normally an then fail to execute with said error message.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** Exception is related to 32/64 bit settings in your C# project. Either set platform target to x86 or if you have it on Any CPU make sure to tick Prefer 32-bit.

[image]
[image]

**How i found out:**

Made a solution in .NET 4.5 according to https://algoslaves.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/nvidia-cuda-hello-world-in-managed-c-and-f-with-use-of-managedcuda/ (same as OP)
used NuGet to add ManagedCuda 6.5 - Standalone

Worked fine

Backup point A.

Changed .NET version to 4.0, used NuGet to remove and add ManagedCuda 6.5 - Standalone:

Exception thrown: Additional information: ErrorIllegalAddress: While executing a kernel, the device encountered a load or store instruction on an invalid memory address.

Switched .NET version to 4.5, used NuGet to remove and add ManagedCuda 6.5 - Standalone:

Exception thrown: Same as above.

Clean solution, Rebuild solution, Build solution:

Exception thrown: Same as above.

Manually deleted every single file/folder generated by Visual Studio:

Exception thrown: Same as above.

Reopen project backed up from point A:

Worked fine.

Manually delete every single file/folder generated by Visual Studio in both Working and Not working project.

Visually compare all files.

Every file is the same except: not working version has extra `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` in MangedCudaTest.csproj

Deleted lines with `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>`.

Not working version finally Worked fine.

Made same changes in my main project, finally Worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution for me was to set the .NET project to 64bit, NOT 32 bit like suggested in aeroson's answer. I think this maybe because I'm using CUDA SDK 7.5 and I read somewhere about 32bit being phased out.